# D3.js TypeError: attempted to assign readonly property

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typeerror, readonly-attribute

I'm trying to display a [forced-directed](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) network graph using D3.js with the network graph json itself generated by Cytoscape.

Edit: Issue is recreated with [Bl.ock Builder](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d03822c31cb77b02a9e365da639180da/dd3b2d4a3b05550274bbb914dce6a32e8693d071)

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    .links line {
        stroke: #999;
        stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .nodes circle {
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id;     }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("onemode2.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));

    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.links);

    function ticked() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

    function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    }

</script>
</html>
```

This should look like https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045. And the strange thing is that this worked with [this data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15xIddOxRrmXbPTgaI0TthlNVMMSx2Hlh/view?usp=sharing).

But what I'm getting looks like: 
[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I reckon that no one here will download your data, set up a page and test your code. Why don't **you** create a plunker or a bl.ocks with the code + data? That way, we can focus only at the problem. You can easily create a blocks here: http://blockbuilder.org/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'm relatively new to this so pardon my rookie mistakes. Here's a [link](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d03822c31cb77b02a9e365da639180da/dd3b2d4a3b05550274bbb914dce6a32e8693d071) to the block I made.

Answer (score -1):

Validate your "links", if either "source" or "target" has no corresponding "id" in "nodes" array that kind of error occurs